# react - communication between unknown child to parent

Tags: reactjs, typescript

assuming we have a parent component, that might have many types of children.

for example:

```
class App extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <parent>
                    <child-1/>
                </parent>
                <parent>
                    <child-2/>
                </parent>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

the parent should be rendered only according to dragging event,
but then its x, y , width, height should be rendered according to its specific child dimensions.

is there a way to get this information from the child?
or to get a reference to a child?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right then you can pass an update function to the children with which they will update the parent when events occur:

```
class Parent extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    render() {
        return (    
            <div className="parent">
                <Child updatePosition={ this.onChildPositionUpdated.bind(this) } />
            </div>
        );
    }

    onChildPositionUpdated(x: number, y: number, width: number, height: number) {
        // calculate things
    }
}

interface ChildProps {
    updatePosition(x: number, y: number, width: number, height: number);
}

class Child extends React.Component<ChildProps, {}> {
    onDrag(...) {
        // get dimensions
        this.props.updatePosition(...);
    }

    render() {
        return // ...
    }
}

class App extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Parent />
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

Another option is to use the [Refs to Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html):

```
class App extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    childs = [];

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <parent>
                    <child-1 ref={ (c) => this.childs.push(c) } />
                </parent>
                <parent>
                    <child-2 ref={ (c) => this.childs.push(c) } />
                </parent>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

Now with the children in the array you can do what ever you need.

Comment: If you dont know your child, you can still pass props to your child:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! The first suggestion requires that I'll declare the structure inside the parent, which is not what I'm looking for.  Regarding the second suggestion, how will the parent be able to reach its child reference via this childs array? Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear from your question what exactly is your scenario so it's hard for me to give you a specific answer. My suggestions show how you can have communication between the components and with that you can tailor a solution to your specific problem. For example, you can use the `refs` approach but have it in the `Parent` instead of the `App`. You can edit your question and explain your exact problem and then I'll be able to give you something more specific